# How to stop Google play services from running in background?

Tags: android, memory, admob

My app uses the library 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0' to run Admob advertisement. However, I dont know why Google play services keep running in the background and it occupies rather much RAM.

[image]

Do you know how to stop this service when I dont want to show the advertisement anymore? Any commment will be appreciated

Comment: that is not your permission to manage google play services. They are used not only by your app.